# Возможно ли запустить метод methodnameX в зависимости от случайного числа X?

Tags: java

Есть класс, в нём есть методы

```
public void test1(){}; 
public void test2(){}; 
public void test3(){};
```

Возможно ли при запуске условия

```
If (main.rand.nextInt(3) == x)
```

запустить метод testX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Random;    
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Test {
    public void test1() {} 
    public void test2() {} 
    public void test3() {}
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        String methodName = "test" + (rnd.nextInt(3) + 1);

        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.example.Test");
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();

        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        method.invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Class.forName("com.example.Test"); в этом месте пишет ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Проверьте исправленный вариант.

Comment: Работает, спасибо, можно ли каким-нибудь образом использовать это в Android Studio? (с throws ReflectiveOperationException)

Comment: В коде android-приложения лучше использовать try-catch блоки для отлова этого исключения, а в остальном никаких проблем.

Answer (score 4):

При использовании функциональных интерфейсов из Java 8 можно создать массив из нужных методов, после чего выбирать и запускать случайный:

```
public class Test
{
    public void test1() { System.out.println("1"); };
    public void test2() { System.out.println("2"); };
    public void test3() { System.out.println("3"); };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        Runnable[] methods = { t::test1, t::test2, t::test3 };
        Random random = new Random();
        Runnable method = methods[random.nextInt(methods.length)];
        method.run();
    }
}
```

Можно вынести вызов метода в отдельный метод, который будет принимать `Test t` в качестве аргумента:

```
public class Test
{
    public void test1() { System.out.println("1"); };
    public void test2() { System.out.println("2"); };
    public void test3() { System.out.println("3"); };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        callRandom(t);
    }

    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final List<Consumer<Test>> methods = Arrays.asList(Test::test1, Test::test2, Test::test3);

    private static void callRandom(Test t)
    {
        Consumer<Test> method = methods.get(random.nextInt(methods.size()));
        method.accept(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я использую Android Studio, мне выдаёт сообщение: "method references are not supported at this language level". Судя по всему, Android SDK не поддерживает эти функции java 8.

Comment: @AlexeyFuri это смотря какая версия API у вас указана в качестве минимальной. [Судя по интернету](https://medium.com/@cesarmcferreira/native-java-8-arrives-on-android-finally-32e117d074ef), при использовании min API level 24, поддержка должна быть. Либо можно воспользоваться [Jack](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=ru). Сам я этим не пользовался, так что подробностей поведать не могу.